# what does calling _close on an elasticsearch alias do?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a ton of indices sharing the alias **events**.
I called **_close** on the **events** alias and now I can't search the **events** alias at all, even if I reopen it using **_open**.

The error I'm getting is:

```
{
   "error": "ClusterBlockException[blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/4/index closed];]",
   "status": 403
}
```

If I make an **_aliases** call, I get back

```
"aliases": {
    "events": {}
}
```

for all of the pertinent indices so it seems like they are all aliased correctly.
Searched the ES documentation but couldn't find much.

<clarification> seems like calling **_open** on the **events** alias just reopens all the indices with that alias, and calling **_close** just closes them all.  which is what i expected to happen.

Comment: oh i think this might be the problem: "Searching an alias is practically the same as specifying both indices on URL during the search. So, if one of the indices is closed, Elasticsearch cannot perform the search, so it generates the error. You will have to remove the index from the alias manually before closing the index." (from http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Alias-and-close-Bug-td4026674.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling close on an elasticsearch alias does exactly what you'd expect it to -- closes all the indices with that alias.  Not sure if this is the best solution, but I ended up re-aliasing closed indices so they were still marked but don't cause searching the alias to fail.